# How to use getTex in Selenium (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, mocha.js

Noob question here, how can I get and log text from an element? Selenium + mocha.js. I've been searching for days now and I constantly get either pending promise or function name. I went through multiple solutions and I am desperate. Here's my current code:

```
const updatedTimeValue = async () => {
  return driver.findElement(By.className("MuiTypography-root jss1141 MuiTypography-body1")).getText().then(function (text) {
    console.log(text)});
}
updatedTimeValue();
console.log(updatedTimeValue());
```

FYI I am not a testing engineer, I've been only coding for a couple of weeks so there's a lot of stuff that I just don't get yet.

Comment: `getText` should be followed by `()` (because it's a method), like this: `getText()`.

Comment: @User456 Thanks, forgot about it, but now it's 'Promise { <pending> }' again tho :v
The rest of the code is just a series of 'await driver.findElement.....click()/sendKeys' if that matters and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coworker helped me and we got it working! I've also changed classname to XPath, but it shouldn't make a difference.

```
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/p[2]/span")));
const initialTimeValue = () =>  driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/p[2]/span")).getText();
await console.log(initialTimeValue().then(console.log));
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it help or not, because i'am beginner too. First of all we need to identify the element with help of any of the locators like id, class, name, xpath or css and then apply getText() method on it to get the text content of the element.[this answer from this website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-text-from-selenium-element-webelement-object)

Comment: I get that part, but since I work in node with asynchronous code I am having a rough time returning text after I get it :/ At least I believe that's the problem

Comment: Link was for Java solution. OP needs _node.js_ based solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To get the result, you would need to call [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) on the promise.
And to log the output, you can do

```
updatedTimeValue().then(console.log);
```

Note that it is the same as

```
updatedTimeValue().then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help!
It doesn't log anything :/ I forgot to mention that I am triggering the script using mocha from the terminal, it probably makes a difference :v
When I run this mess of a code: `console.log(updatedTimeValue().then(console.log));` then it logs promise pending.